# How to remove chosen variable from array list?

Tags: java, arrays, list, variables

This is a program which stores employee's information (salary, names, ID#, date hired) in an array list. When called upon (after pressing 'listButton') it lists this information in a Field for employer to look at. The employee needs to remove an employee from the list, there is a removeButton, so what would allow the employer to delete a name from the list of employees?

```
public class EmployeeView extends FrameView {

    class Company {
        String ID, firstName, lastName, annualSal, startDate, mileage;

        Company (String _ID, String _firstName,String _lastName, String _annualSal, String _startDate) {
            ID = _ID;
            firstName = _firstName;
            lastName = _lastName;
            annualSal = _annualSal;
            startDate = _startDate;
        }
    }

    /** Define the ArrayList */
    ArrayList <Company> employee = new ArrayList <Company>();

    String ID, firstName, lastName, annualSal, startDate;

    public EmployeeView(SingleFrameApplication app) {
       //GUI stuff...
    }

    private void AddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        ID = IDField.getText();
        firstName = firstNameField.getText();
        lastName = lastNameField.getText();
        annualSal = annualSalField.getText();
        startDate = startDateField.getText();

        Company c = new Company(ID, firstName, lastName, annualSal, startDate);
        employee.add(c);
    }

    private void ListActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        String temp = "";

        for (int x=0; x<=employee.size()-1; x++) {
            temp = temp + employee.get(x).ID + " "
                    + employee.get(x).firstName + " "
                    + employee.get(x).lastName + " "
                    + employee.get(x).annualSal + " "
                    + employee.get(x).startDate + "\n";
        }
        employeeTArea.setText(temp);

}

    private void removeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    //My attempt... it didn't do anything though           
            int remove = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < employee.size()-1; j++) {
                if (remove == Integer.parseInt(IDField.getText())) {

                   employee.remove(j);
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are initializing `remove=0`, what you want to do is:

```
for (int j = 0; j < employee.size()-1; j++) {
                if (j == Integer.parseInt(IDField.getText())) {
                   employee.RemoveAt(j);
                }
            }
```

You don't need a remove variable. This is providing that `IDField.getText()` is the index of the `employee` you want to remove from the `ArrayList`

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the for loop and just do [employee.remove(company)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29).